# did include_once function create http request

Tags: php, http

I am using include_once function in my code several times for many files my fear is it it create http request every time a new file loads

like

```
  include_once 'example.php'
```

tell

Comment: It doesn't, unless your include filename is a url (e.g. http://localhost/example.php)... in your example, it's just a filename on the local filesystem

Comment: @MarkBaker: To further on trouble the TS's mind, what happens if you put something `http://`-ish into the include path directive? :s

Comment: The `include` family of "functions" always operate on the local file system unless you supply a full valid URL. Like any other construct in PHP that takes the path to a file as an argument. Which you would know if you had bothered to [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) properly.

Comment: Pls read some docs about include/require behavior in PHP. This is all PHP server side script inclusion, from your browser it is just one, single HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the include statements accesses the file via the file system, it does not generate an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code runs on the server side, so there are no HTTP requests unless you make one yourself.